# One of the worst questions ever was deleted but

Tags: discussion

I had voted to close as "too broad" and wonder why that doesn't show in the comment section?

- [I never heard of Ubuntu. What's Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1176653)

On second sober thought maybe my VTC was "Primarily Opinion Orientated" but it's GONE so I can't be sure.

Comment: Why would it show in the comment section? The bot makes comments for duplicate votes but nothing automatically posts comments for any other close reasons. The post was never closed either, in case you were thinking of the close banner.

Comment: You voted primarily opinion based, if it matters.

Comment: @Seth Well it does show a comment that's a comment but not the VTC which are kind of important comments. Thanks for confirming how I voted to close. What would you have voted to close if you were allowed to vote? :)

Comment: A VTC isn't a comment. Other than the `close (x)` button there is no indication of a close vote until the post is actually closed. Which is why you don't see anything. 4 votes were cast but the post was deleted before the 5th vote came in. As to what I would have done, probably edit it and encourage someone to answer, tbh.

Comment: @Seth Haha that post was beyond editing salvation! When VTC as a duplicate that shows up in comments doesn't it? Of course that off-the-wall question would have no duplicate :)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix that's a special case where it links to possible duplicates - that's not the norm for VTC though

Comment: @ThomasWard Good point. Most my VTC's are duplicates and I'm so used to seeing the comments there. I wonder if it would be beneficial for people to see VTC's for other categories in the comments too. Might influence their voting (outside of queue review which I don't visit anymore sadly).

Comment: Automatic comments also appear when a custom off-topic reason is used., "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic ......"

Comment: @Kulfy I will try to remember that for the next guy with a quadrillion dollars that isn't smart enough to hire consultants like you or I to tell him what Ubuntu is LOL

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix By the way FYI, the OP was network wide troller. They posted on SU: "How to login on SU?" (really??). On SO they posted: "How to print Hello World in python?" and got instantly suspended. One of their answer on AU and Japanese language was: "The solution is subscribe to PewDiePie on YouTube". On travel they posted: "Can I bring meat to the Netherlands?". On SF: "What is a server?".

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix "What is ubuntu" is a valid question. Not everyone is as technically literate as those of us providing the answers (the whole reason this ob exists at all lol). Was the OP a troll? Sure, but they posted the question and we can edit it, answer it, and bam, quality content. No reason we need the OP to stick around. Granted, this one was pretty bad and I have no inclination to undelete it, but deleting things is rarely my first impulse :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post was deleted for purposes of moderation by the system automatically.

As a moderator and a user, though, I don't think it served any real purpose here, and even if it hadn't been deleted due to flags and system intervention, it probably still would have been closed as too broad or such.

So I'd say you were fine, but keep in mind close votes for "unclear what you're asking" *do not* get reflected in the comments.  They're in the moderator-visible close votes / flags logs.

Comment: No doubt it should have been deleted. In fact I had emailed the link to myself so I could delete vote it when I got home. I thought of using "unclear what you are asking" VTC reason because no one has a quad-trillion dollars yet but went with "primarily opinion orientated" because "What is Ubuntu?" means different things to a multi-user server CLI user than Single-User Desktop GUI user. Even in the latter to me Ubuntu means BASH on Linux and BASH on Windows because that's what I primarily do with it...